# Display single SPECIFIC Instagram photo - possible?

Tags: html, css, instagram, instagram-api

Emphasis on ***specific*** photo here.

I'm aware of all the Instagram plugins out there, and the Instagram API, however I'm trying to figure out a way to display a single specific photo from Instagram. Not by tag, or by username, but preferably from the Instagram URL, or even with a photo ID.

I want something similar to this: (where the Instagram photo covers the background of the div)

```
<div class="instagram-photo" 
     style="background-image:URL(*instagram_photo_url_here*);
            background-size:cover">
</div>
```

I'm happy to link to the photo for photo credit and all that.

Is this possible? I've searched for hours and nothing comes up, I've got to be overlooking something.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Just put the photo URL in. Example with a random Instagram page: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n35m14b6/1/). Where does it go wrong?

Comment: Wait a minute, I should have asked this immediately. Which photo is it?

Comment: Where did you get the URL of Instagram photo? For instance this photo - https://www.instagram.com/p/8mb1rjun86/

Comment: In the page source. https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpt1/t51.2885-15/e35/12145185_1505270246463454_786362645_n.jpg

Comment: I have an answer for you, and understand what exactly you want to achieve, but the question is, do you want to use JavaScript (a delay) or PHP (fast and better UX)

Comment: @AdamAzad i'd prefer javascript as the website I'm building is made in ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to come up with an answer, Instagram provides an easy to get the media directly using [Media redirect](https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect), by adding `/media/?size={size}` to end of any photo permalink

> Desired size of the resulting media. Supported values are `t`
>   (thumbnail), `m` (medium), `l` (large). Defaults to m.

Examples;

- https://www.instagram.com/p/8l2vIrhQQ_/media/?size=l
- https://www.instagram.com/p/7TDiYJBQdf/media/?size=m
- https://www.instagram.com/p/cn5KZWmJp1/media/?size=t

And if you're *lasy* or want bulk changing at once, I wrote a jQuery snippet for this; <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/30j9jjgd/)</kbd>

Here's your final HTML for your attempt

```css
body {
  padding:10px;
}
.instagram-photo {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  background:#ffffff;
  height:500px;
  border:2px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
   <div class="instagram-photo" style="background-image: url(https://instagram.com/p/-FP1PjBQRd/media/?size=l); background-size: cover;"></div>
  <div class="instagram-photo" style="background-image: url(https://instagram.com/p/8l2vIrhQQ_/media/?size=l); background-size: cover;"></div>
  <div class="instagram-photo" style="background-image: url(https://instagram.com/p/-XNiICnxXO/media/?size=l); background-size: cover;"></div>
  <div class="instagram-photo" style="background-image: url(https://instagram.com/p/cn5KZWmJp1/media/?size=l); background-size: cover;"></div>
  <div class="instagram-photo" style="background-image: url(https://instagram.com/p/7TDiYJBQdf/media/?size=l); background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time and effort to do this. This is exactly what I was looking for and works beautifully!